# Least worst option to secure database connection string for distributed wpf application to users with local admin rights

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I have tried to read about different solutions regarding this, and I understand that the way to go depends very much on each individual scenario. This was a good link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164054.aspx .

I would appreciate some expert advice regarding this specific scenario.

Scenario:

WPF application with a sql compact database which will be distributed to clients with local admin rights. The application can't rely on an internet connection all the time. None, except for the application itself should be able to gain access to the database. So, what would be the best scenario for this, or least worst? I mean so that the users can't get the database credentials.

**Edit:** Database is engine default encrypted, and has a strong password.

Options:

- Encrypting Configuration File Sections Using Protected Configuration ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

  - With DPAPIProtectedConfigurationProvider (using client keys):

    - Pros: Harder to get hold of the keys...?? Or maybe not when the user has local admin rights..?
    - Cons: The connection string can only be decrypted on the computer on which it was encrypted. Has to be encrypted on the client machine. Either when application runs for the first time, or with a custom action when installing with a MSI. Both of them is easy to get hold of the connection string if you know that you have to look before executing.
  - With RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider (using supplied keys):

    - Pros: Data is encrypted when distributed
    - Cons: Keys has to be stored somewhere, and is easier to compromise..?? Probably not a difference to DPAPIProtectedConfigurationProvider as long as the user has local admin rights..?
- Using Windows Security:

  - Cons: User can easily connect to database with it's own credentials. So this is not an option.
- Data hiding:

  - Cons: To easy to get hold of the connection string when reverse engineering by example. This is not an option standalone.
- Other options?

I see a lot of examples where it is suggested to use DPAPIProtectedConfigurationProvider and encrypting the connection string in the app.config first time it is executed or with a custom action during install.

Well, I believe that the least worst option is encrypting app.config using RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider with a custom RSA key that is generated each time (with logic that makes the key the same each time). Then all this code is obfuscated. In that way the app.config can be distributed with encrypted connection string.

I know that the credentials still can be compromised and that there is no way to avoid this 100% in this scenario. It's all about choosing the least worst option.

Now I would appreciate your opinion... Thanks!

Comment: I guess "least worst" and "best" is related and somehow go hand in hand. When it comes to preventing cracking, the term "least worst" is more suiting than "best", it somehow states that it's just making it a bit harder for an intruder to break the code. The term "best" is just to positive when discussing such a topic... To my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: you cannot prevent a determined local admin to get access to this database.

Here's what I -- as a determined user -- would do (I have done it in the past with other programs): I would attach a debugger to the running process and look at the memory to find the plain connection string (of course I am simplifying -- but it works).

Another option would be to use the debugger to hijack your IDbCommand objects to execute arbitrary SQL code, no need for me to find the connection credentials, your application manages the connection for me.

So it really comes down to: how competent and determined are your users? how important is your database? how determined are you?
It's the classical hacker trade-off: how much effort do you want to put into this to discourage your users from cracking your app, knowing that in the end it's always technically possible to crack it?

The bare minimum I would do:

1. Encrypt the raw connection string. You have covered this part.
2. Maybe do the encryption in code rather than rely on the built-in app.config section encryption. The problem with the built-in one is that it's self-documenting. People with .net knowledge will know just by reading it how it's encrypted. The security is provided by securing the keys, but they can't really be hidden from a local administrator. There's even a command-line tool to decrypt the section (if you pass the correct keys)! Performing the decryption in code makes it less obvious which algorithm you're using and needs more work to actually decrypt it.
   NOTE: you should still use a strong cryptography provider such as those you've mentionned. I am *not* saying that you should invent your own cryptographic cipher, rather than you may *hide* the cipher you use in the program itself rather than the config file.
3. Obfuscate the compiled assembly. Otherwise it's just to easy to open it up in a tool such as IlSpy, and even modify it (e.g. to dump the plain connection string).
4. Add some debugger traps to prevent attaching a debugger to your process.

Note that both 3. and 4. would be more efficient with a mixed mode assembly (one that contains native code as well as managed code).

This is a start. Maybe other people will have more ideas.

---

Of course this was just the application side. The embedded database should be appropriately protected as well. It should be encrypted to start with.

Comment: +1 for sharing your approach to get the connection string, and "4. Add some debugger traps to prevent attaching a debugger to your process.". The database is encrypted, I will update the post to contain this. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Another idea, but which may be hard to apply. If your database content is really important, true security means not sending the data to the user -- in any form. Classical way is to use a secure server to connect to the database, but you said customers need an "offline" mode. Another solution is to embed a different database _per customer_, with only the data this customer is allowed to see. If he cracks it, he wouldn't get more insight than what he's able to see in the application anyway. This is 100% secure but needs much effort (per customer delivery).

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to get some more answers about this, just to get more sides/inputs. Thanks for your answer and comments, I will mark yours as the accepted answer.